# Unable to edit item of a SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, selectlistitem

I have an object like this :

```
public class AppointmentStatus 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string I18NKey {get;set;}
}
```

The I18NKey refers to a key for the translation.

In my form, I create a dropdownlist using a Select list :

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Id, new SelectList(MyListOfStatus, "Id","I18NKey")
```

With this I retrieve the value of the key as text, I want to edit the property text in every SelectListItem.

I used something like this :

```
public static SelectList TranslateValue(SelectList list)
    {
        foreach (var tmp in list)
        {
            tmp.Text = I18nHelper.Message(tmp.Text);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But it changes nothing ! The Text property is still the same, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution : A SelectList seems to be based on the IEnumerable it needs.
The property Text of every SelectListItem are **dynamics** and depends on every item of the IEnumerable.

We need to change the **IEnumerable**, not the **SelectList** :

What I finally did :

```
public class AppointmentStatus 
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string I18NKey {get;set;}
     public string Translation {get;set;}
}

public static IEnumerable<AppointmentStatus> TranslateValue(IEnumerable<AppointmentStatus> list)
    {
        foreach (var tmp in list)
        {
            tmp.Translation = I18nHelper.Message(tmp.I18NKey);
        }
        return list;
    }

Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Id, new SelectList(HelperClass.TranslateValue(MyListOfStatus), "Id","Translation")
```

Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the binding in drop down:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, 
       TranslateValue(new SelectList(MyListOfStatus, "Id","I18NKey"))
```

Also check if your `I18nHelper.Message` works as expected.

Comment: This is what I tried, and yes I18NHelper.Message works like a charm